# Why is my Data Missing While Parsing & Writing to an Excel Sheet with xlwt? - Python

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have an issue parsing dictionary data into excel (".xls") where not all the values in the dictionary end up in my excel file ("testbk1.xls"). I've been trying to identify what the issue is for some time & then resolve to seeking further insight ... ** Can someone highlight where the problem is?**

Expected Excel Output

[image]

Resulting Excel Output

[image]

Code:

```
    import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sample1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
data = {'10.110.10.10': [('ar01', 'MODULE', '', 'Modules', 'Catalyst 6500 Series Supervisor Modules', 'PPL94941MG', '31-1-2018'), ('ar01', 'MODULE', '', 'Modules', 'TM', 'FQW10470NTF', '31-3-2018'), ('ar01', 'MODULE', '', 'Modules', 'TM', 'FNS120010WA', '31-3-2018')], '110.110.1.1': [('ar02', 'MODULE', '', 'Modules', 'Catalyst 6500 Series Supervisor Modules', 'RAL1138ZEC1', '31-1-2018'), ('ar02', 'MODULE', '', 'Modules', 'TM', 'OPA10233U08', '31-3-2018'), ('ar02', 'MODULE', '', 'Modules', 'TM', 'HJG1267U9U4', '31-3-2018')], '10.110.1.97': [('EEE-RT', 'MODULE', '', 'Modules', 'TM', 'WGC4556U5UA', '31-3-2018')], '10.110.1.225': [('SSS-IGW-RT-1', 'MODULE', 'MM4', 'Modules', 'TM', 'HJM151RTY6A', '31-3-2018'), ('SSS-IGW-RT-1', 'MODULE', 'MM4', 'Modules', 'TM', 'TTTUI909E7', '31-3-2018'), ('SSS-IGW-RT-1', 'MODULE', 'MM4', 'Modules', 'TM', 'MMM1WEF7813', '31-3-2018')], '10.110.172.2': [('SSS-IGW-RT-2', 'MODULE', 'MM4', 'Modules', 'TM', 'AGM61CGBUDU', '31-3-2018'), ('SSS-IGW-RT-2', 'MODULE', 'MM4', 'Modules', 'TM', 'RYUYUH3L9E9', '31-3-2018'), ('SSS-IGW-RT-2', 'MODULE', 'MM4', 'Modules', 'TM', 'YUI23RT9EW', '31-3-2018')]}

def write_to_file():
    header = ['IP Address', 'Host Name', 'Equipment Type', 'DC', 'Product Type', 'Product Family', 'Serial Number','Hardware EoS']
    n = 0
    for i in header:
        sheet1.write(0, n, i)
        n += 1
    for col, caption in enumerate(data, 1):
        sheet1.write(col, 0, caption)
        for row, dt in enumerate(data[caption], 1):
            for col_no, q in enumerate(dt):
                if not q:
                    q = 'NA'
                if col_no == 0:
                    sheet1.write(row, col_no, caption)
                    sheet1.write(row, col_no+1, q)
                else:
                    sheet1.write(row, col_no+1, q)
    book.save("testbk1.xls")
    return
write_to_file()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. It was found that the rows are being overwritten because the row value was not changing from "for row, dt in enumerate(data[caption], 1)".

I introduced "row_cnt" variable to increment the row number instead of using the "row" index in "for row, dt in enumerate(data[caption], 1):". That resolved it.!

```
def write_to_file():
    header = ['IP Address', 'Host Name', 'Equipment Type', 'DC', 'Product Type', 'Product Family', 'Serial Number','Hardware EoS']
    n = 0
    for i in header:
        sheet1.write(0, n, i)
        n += 1
    row_cnt = 1
    for col, caption in enumerate(data, 1):
        sheet1.write(col, 0, caption)
        for row, dt in enumerate(data[caption], 1):
            for col_no, q in enumerate(dt):
                if not q:
                    q = 'NA'
                if col_no == 0:
                    sheet1.write(row_cnt, col_no, caption)
                    sheet1.write(row_cnt, col_no+1, q)
                else:
                    sheet1.write(row_cnt, col_no+1, q)
            row_cnt += 1
    book.save("testbk1.xls")
    return
```